# Cant find Bug in my AdMob android code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob, adview

I have used BANNER size AdView in my app. I have followed all the steps as in the google admob site. I have attached the xml code [AdView Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVRKS.png) and Java code [Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAFXH.png) below

I can see the preview of Banner AdView in Android Studio. But Ad is not visible in my mobile after installed the app. I have double checked the unitid and app id.

Comment: post your xml and java code

Comment: @HUSTLE : I have attached the codes as image

Comment: is this really your full xml layout code?

Comment: Many possibilities occur as seen your code.
1.) Remove MobileAds.initialize you don't need this because you already apply the unit-id to your xml.
2) remove addTestDevice it just shows the test ad not the real ad so remove it.

Comment: @HUSTLE : Full xml code is big. I couldn't attach full code here. That's wht I've attached adview code alone

Comment: Another reason not showing banner has fixed size 320*50 and as seen you xml you apply margin left try to remove it

Comment: @AndyDeveloper : I have tried your points also. Still ad is not visible in my mobile

Comment: we need to see the full layout code if there is any unwanted paddings

Comment: Main important thing I was noticed the key you are applying after /75549 is not a valid key so please checked the once again may be it is around 10charchter after /. Or I though key is valid but for security you are not showing the full key. Please let me know

Comment: @AndyDeveloper : Now Its working. Im only edited the unitid and appid as I publish in the net. I tried all your steps. Its working fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Muhilan welcome :)